# Unique subdomain for sending emails - HOW?

Tags: email, subdomain, unique, blacklist, intercom

This is not an easy question because its a technique I have never seen before.
I recently received an email from a website I am subscribed and the email sender was something like this:

> name@company-91e363c0cfc9.mail.intercom.io

I have a Saas software where users can send email marketing.
The problem is that the sender email is no-reply@domain.com for every one of them.
I was thinking about "what if" some of my customers sends junk and my domain gets blacklisted?

Looking at the technique Intercom is using I thought that it is a good way to solve the blacklist issue.

Let assume a customer sends spam, is the hole domain blacklisted (mail.intercom.io) or just @company-91e363c0cfc9.mail.intercom.io ?

I have the following questions:

- What is the name of this technique/configuration.
- Is it a good technique to solve getting the root domain
  blacklisted ?
- How can I configure this on my server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are create a sub-domain for each of their clients in DNS, as you can see by the [MX Record Lookup](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/mx/company-91e363c0cfc9.mail.intercom.io/) of the domain you provided. When an email get sent out, they have an outgoing IP address on the email, which you didn't provide. The outgoing IP is going to blacklisted, it doesn't matter if the 50 sub-domains are different, the Outgoing IP (Sending IP) is going to get blacklisted. I don't think you're going to be able to working around an abusive customer, if the IP's are the same.

I spoke to some hosting companies that have similar issues and before they every allow a client to send mail, they need a clean report from this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/email-authentication.html). But, even with a clean configuration and authentication, that doesn't prevent spam content from being sent. When that happens the IP owner has to address it, ultimately barring that customer from sending spam, if they don't correct the behavior.

You can always monitor your IP's for Blacklists and you should, but you're going to get a ton of abuse reports coming in from various providers, if it's a problem.